# binomiales: Con 5 hombres y 4 mujeres, ¿cuántos grupos formados por 3 hombres y 2 mujeres se pueden formar?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Para calcular cuantos grupos formados por 5 hombres y 4 mujeres se pueden formar, podríamos utilizar los coeficientes binomiales.
El coeficiente binomial `$\binom{5}{3}$` representa el número de formas en las que podemos elegir 3 hombres de un conjunto de 5 hombres, y `$\binom{4}{2}$` representa el número de formas en las que podemos elegir 2 mujeres de un conjunto de 4 mujeres.

Para calcular el resultado, multiplicamos los dos coeficientes binomiales:

```
$\binom{5}{3} \cdot \binom{4}{2} = \frac {5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{3 \cdot 2} \cdot \frac{4 \cdot 3}{2} = 20 \cdot 6 = 120$
```

Esto significa que hay 120 grupos diferentes que se pueden formar con 3 hombres y 2 mujeres a partir de los conjuntos dados.

La fórmula utilizada se basa en el principio de multiplicación, donde multiplicamos el número de opciones en cada paso independiente del proceso de selección para obtener el resultado total.

```
$\binom{5}{3} \binom{4}{2} = \frac {5 \times 4 \times 3}{3 \times  2} \times \frac{4 \times 3}{2} = 20 \times 6 = 120$
```

Intentamos hacerlo con Python de la siguiente manera.

```
import pandas as pd

# Crear un DataFrame con los hombres y mujeres
data = {
    'Hombres': ['H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5'],
    'Mujeres': ['M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4']
}

# Crear el DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Calcular el número de grupos
num_grupos_hombres = 3
num_grupos_mujeres = 2

# Obtener los coeficientes binomiales
coeficientes_hombres = len(df['Hombres'])
coeficientes_mujeres = len(df['Mujeres'])

# Calcular el número de grupos formados por hombres y mujeres
num_grupos = coeficientes_hombres * (coeficientes_hombres - 1) * (coeficientes_hombres - 2) // (num_grupos_hombres * (num_grupos_hombres - 1) * (num_grupos_hombres - 2))
num_grupos *= coeficientes_mujeres * (coeficientes_mujeres - 1) // (num_grupos_mujeres * (num_grupos_mujeres - 1))

# Imprimir el resultado
print("El número de grupos formados por 3 hombres y 2 mujeres es:", num_grupos)
```

Me devuelve el error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[46], line 10
      4 data = {
      5     'Hombres': ['H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5'],
      6     'Mujeres': ['M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4']
      7 }
      9 # Crear el DataFrame
---> 10 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
     12 # Calcular el número de grupos
     13 num_grupos_hombres = 3

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:664, in DataFrame.__init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    658     mgr = self._init_mgr(
    659         data, axes={"index": index, "columns": columns}, dtype=dtype, copy=copy
    660     )
    662 elif isinstance(data, dict):
    663     # GH#38939 de facto copy defaults to False only in non-dict cases
--> 664     mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
    665 elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    666     import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:493, in dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype, typ, copy)
    489     else:
    490         # dtype check to exclude e.g. range objects, scalars
    491         arrays = [x.copy() if hasattr(x, "dtype") else x for x in arrays]
--> 493 return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:118, in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype, verify_integrity, typ, consolidate)
    115 if verify_integrity:
    116     # figure out the index, if necessary
    117     if index is None:
--> 118         index = _extract_index(arrays)
    119     else:
    120         index = ensure_index(index)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:666, in _extract_index(data)
    664 lengths = list(set(raw_lengths))
    665 if len(lengths) > 1:
--> 666     raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")
    668 if have_dicts:
    669     raise ValueError(
    670         "Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering."
    671     )

ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
```

que no acabo de entender ya que parto de la premisa de 5 hombres y 4 mujeres. ¿Qué error cómeto en este código?. ¿Hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: El error es simple, estas creando un Dataframe con una columna con 5 valores y otra columna con 4, cosa que para un Dataframe es ilógico, tiene 5 o 4 filas. Eventualmente, te podría sugerir que agregues un valor nulo en la columna de las mujeres para unificar la cantidad de filas. O bien trabajalo como dos dataframes  o inclusos listas distintas.

Comment: De hecho, en el código que muestras, ni siquiera importa crear un dataframe, por que no haces nada con este

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Antes que nada, tu operación donde calculas `num_grupos` da `60` pero en tu pregunta mencionas que el resultado es `120`. El resultado correcto es `60` ya que `(5*4*3)/(3*2) = 10` y no `20`.

Como no mencionas restricciones en tu ejercicio, una forma muy fácil de hacerlo, es utilizando la librería `scipy`.

Esta librería tiene 2 funciones que calculan los coeficientes binomiales `binom` y `comb` y ambas devuelven los mismos resultados.

```
import scipy.special

coeficientes_hombres = 5
num_grupos_hombres = 3
coeficientes_mujeres = 4
num_grupos_mujeres = 2

print(scipy.special.binom(coeficientes_hombres, num_grupos_hombres) * scipy.special.binom(coeficientes_mujeres, num_grupos_mujeres))
print(scipy.special.comb(coeficientes_hombres, num_grupos_hombres) * scipy.special.comb(coeficientes_mujeres, num_grupos_mujeres))
```

Esto imprime:

```
60.0
60.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es otra solución:

```
from itertools import combinations

# Definir la cantidad de hombres y mujeres
num_hombres = 5
num_mujeres = 4

# Calcular todas las combinaciones posibles
combinaciones_hombres = list(combinations(range(num_hombres), 3))
combinaciones_mujeres = list(combinations(range(num_mujeres), 2))

# Calcular el número total de grupos posibles
num_grupos = len(combinaciones_hombres) * len(combinaciones_mujeres)

# Imprimir el resultado
print("Número de grupos posibles:", num_grupos)
```